# Codeigniter: 'You did not select a file to upload', when data sent through Ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I'm trying to insert form data through Ajax and Codeigniter but am unable to insert the data, getting 'You did not select a file to upload' error. Facing problem with the file uploads. I have no idea of how to pass input file data through jQuery ajax.

Here is my jQuery code:

```
$('#saveAddress').click(function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        var add = $('#address').val();
        var city = $('#city').val();
        var state = $('#sate').val();
        var district = $('#district').val();
        var pcode = $('#pincode').val();
        var pType = $('#proofType').val();
        var aProof = new FormData($('#addressProof'));
        if(add != "" && city != "" && state != "" && district != "" && pcode != "" && pType != "" && aProof != ""){
            $.ajax({
                type:"POST",
                url:"<?php echo base_url();?>index.php/MyApp/addressDetails",
                data:{address:add,city:city,state:state,district:district,pincode:pcode,proofType:pType,addressProof:aProof},
                contentType: false,
                processData: false,
                beforeSend: function() {
                    jQuery('#pbo-loader').css('display','block');
                },
                success:function(response){
                    console.log(response);
                },
                error: function(jqXHR) { 
                    console.log(jqXHR); 
                },
                complete:function(){
                    jQuery('#pbo-loader').css('display','none');
                }
           });   
        }
    });
```

controller code:

```
public function addressDetails(){
            if($this->session->userdata('currently_logged_in')){
                $pbonum = $this->session->userdata('pbonum');
                if(isset($_POST)){
                    $noti['add'] = $this->input->post('address');
                    $noti['img'] = $this->input->post('addressProof');
                    $thumb = 'addressProof_'.$pbonum;
                    $config['file_name']            = $thumb;
                    $config['upload_path']          = 'uploads/kyc/address/';
                    $config['allowed_types']        = 'gif|jpg|png|pdf|doc';
                    $config['max_size']             = 2000;
                    $this->load->library('upload');
                    $this->upload->initialize($config);
                    if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload('addressProof'))
                    {
                            $noti['error'] = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        $data = array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data());
                        $thumb = $data['file_name'];
                        $res = $this->CustomerModel->updateAddressDetails($thumb);
                        if($res == 1){
                            $noti['status'] = "success";
                        }
                        else{
                            $noti['status'] = "failed";
                        }
                    }
                    print_r($noti);
                }
            }
            else{
                $this->load->view('templates/header');  
                $this->load->view('signin');
                $this->load->view('templates/footer');  
            }
        }
```

Comment: You can not send file using pure ajax submit. Use jquery form plugin to simulate a multipart form submition:  http://malsup.com/jquery/form/ and dont foget to set your form as a multipart

Comment: @ali you are wrong - the `FormData` Object is able to do this. @akhil try `var aProof = new FormData($('#addressProof')[0]);` because you need to use the standard javascript object here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in order to achieve what you want you need to use the standard javascript object here

```
var aProof = new FormData($('#addressProof')[0]);
```

Furthermore, you don't need to set your data manually, try the code below

```
$.ajax({
    type:"POST",
    url:"<?php echo base_url();?>index.php/MyApp/addressDetails",
    data:aProof,
    contentType: false,
    processData: false,
    beforeSend: function() {
        jQuery('#pbo-loader').css('display','block');
    },
    success:function(response){
        console.log(response);
    },
    error: function(jqXHR) { 
        console.log(jqXHR); 
    },
    complete:function(){
        jQuery('#pbo-loader').css('display','none');
    }
});
```

Comment: It worked, thanks a lot!
Why we need to give [0] to the form id?

Comment: because `$('#addressProof')` gives you the jQuery object and  `$('#addressProof')[0]` returns you the native javascript dom object and since FormData is a native JS Object (ant not a jQuery object) - you've to pass a native JS object therefore - for further information read the article https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/faq/how-do-i-pull-a-native-dom-element-from-a-jquery-object/